# Android studio: DatePickerDialog cant setMaxDate to 1998

Tags: android

I'm making a registration form with a birthdate detail. But I need it to be set it as maximum of 18 years ago. But when I `view.setMaxDate(1998);` nothing happens on the first set, but on second set the max date is `1970` in the dialog. Here is my code guys.

## Initialize calendar

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = 1998;
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

## the DatePickerDialog

```
public void showDialogOnButtonClick(){
    etBirthDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBirthDate);

    etBirthDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  if(id == DIALOG_ID) {
      return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpListener, year_x, month_x, day_x);
  }
      return null;
  }

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    view.setMaxDate(1998);
    year_x = year;
    month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
    day_x = dayOfMonth;
    etBirthDate.setText(month_x + "/" +  day_x + "/" + year_x);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line of setting 1998 in setMaxDate seems to be wrong. This method of DatePicker needs Epoch. Pls set something like this and it will work.

```
//view.setMaxDate(1998);
view.setMaxDate(1546210800000L);
```

So in your case do this

```
view.setMaxDate(883612800000); // this will set date as 1st Jan 1998. Change the time accordingly.
```

Comment: Thanks sir! This worked! But, when I'm clicking on the dialog on the first time this doesnt work. only on the second time i pressed the dialog.

Comment: I think that it because of onfocus() listener being called first before it is calling on click. Pls try to disable onfocus() listener or catch that first. I remember few posts on StackOverFlow. I think this is common issue.  Let me hunt if i can.

Comment: Once again. Thanks sir. :))

Comment: But I dont have `onFocusListener()` sir.

Answer (score 0):

the parameter to `setMaxDate(...)` should be a Unix Timestamp.

In this case, 1/1 1998 would match the timestamp `883612800000`

However, what you probably want to do is take the current timestamp and subtract the number of seconds in 18 years from it.

To make it have the correct date from the beginning, chanage

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if(id == DIALOG_ID) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpListener, year_x, month_x, day_x);
    }
    return null;
}
```

to

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if(id == DIALOG_ID) {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dpListener, year_x, month_x, day_x);
        dialog.setMaxDate(883612800000);
        return dialog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Setting it to `view.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 883612800);` makes the maxData to 2016 sir. How can I make it to 1998?

Comment: But, when I'm clicking on the dialog on the first time this doesnt work. only on the second time i pressed the dialog.

Comment: not `view.setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 883612800);`, `view.setMaxDate(883612800);`. 883612800 is the number of seconds from  00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 1/1 1998. The other solution requires you to compute how many seconds make up 18 Years (and subtract that from System.currentTimeMillis()). And as @SachiinGupta pointed out, it should be multiplied by 1000, because java uses Milliseconds

Comment: And for your first time problem, see my updated answer

Comment: try dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(...)